# Automatically text written in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have seen in some webpages that text is automatically being written on the webpage, It takes some seconds to write the text just like a terminal. 
I want to know how we can do that ? Will Try To Search for example, So that you guys can easily understand, But if someone has seen anything like that and know how to do then please share :)

Comment: Search first, try something. Then come here.

Comment: The problem is I don't know what i can say to that technique, If I know the name :| then why would i came here to ask :| @fbynite

Comment: If you google for "javascript typing effect" you get more than plenty of hits.

Comment: @Juhana Oh yes i got that, THanks :D 
REALLY HELPED :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pure javascript, google search
http://thezillion.wordpress.com/2012/02/27/javascript-typing-effect/

```
  <html>
    <head>
    <title>Typing Effect - by Zillion</title>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    var index = 0;
    var text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque tincidunt, nulla at tempus tristique, nisl leo molestie est, ut vestibulum mauris mauris a odio. Sed at massa vitae ipsum venenatis porta. Integer iaculis pretium tempus. Donec viverra sollicitudin velit non gravida. Phasellus sit amet tortor odio. Vivamus lectus nisl, suscipit porttitor bibendum ut, tristique quis dui. Vestibulum non eros leo. Maecenas tincidunt semper turpis, a tristique purus pretium sit amet. Praesent nec neque tortor.Donec suscipit tristique ante quis molestie. Phasellus ac lacus non felis faucibus dictum vitae ac ipsum. Sed pharetra nulla sodales nulla porta imperdiet. Quisque pretium hendrerit laoreet.';
    // Here you can put in the text you want to make it type.
    function type()
    {
    document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML += text.charAt(index);
    index += 1;
    var t = setTimeout('type()',100);
    // The time taken for each character here is 100ms. You can change it if you want.
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload='type()'>
    <!-- And here, you create the container in which you display the typed text -->
    <div id='screen'></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

another one

http://jsfiddle.net/AniHouse/x9Ls5/

Comment: Thanks :D , Can you also tell how can i increase it's speed :D ?

Comment: it is written in comments, near the setTimeout function. change setTimeout('type()',50) for e.g.

Comment: as a new user, remember to do your research before asking, and remember to mark answer/upvotes for future viewers. you seem like you wanted a complete code without even typing a word.

Comment: ok I will do research next time, :) and Yea i will mark answer as correct, but it's saying me to wait for some minutes that's why i'm waiting :) And the reason i ask without searching because i was in need of a keyword that would take me to the tutorial, Thanks once again ;)

Comment: Can you tell if what should i do i want to use <br> (skip a line) after some lines, Actually i'm new in JS.

Comment: have a look : http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/jsTypewriter/